# Удалить строки целиком, которые начинаются с None

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строки:

```
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>0</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
None
<FIELD.1109>
нет
</FIELD.1109>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>0</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
=============================================
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>1</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>100</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.701>
<SUBFIELD.3>10000768</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Шерстюченко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>О. А.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.701>
<FIELD.1109>
0.286
</FIELD.1109>
=============================================
```

Хотелось бы удалить все строки целиком, в которых встречается "None". Пыталась сделать так:

```
prefixes = 'None'
newlist = [x for x in authors_a if not x.startswith(prefixes)]
print(newlist)
```

Но результат такой:

```
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>0</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
['N', 'o', 'n', 'e']
<FIELD.1109>
нет
</FIELD.1109>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>0</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
=============================================
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>1</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>100</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
['<', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', '7', '0', '1', '>', '\n', '<', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', '3', '>', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '6', '8', '<', '/', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', '3', '>', '<', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', 'A', '>', 'Ш', 'е', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ю', 'ч', 'е', 'н', 'к', 'о', '<', '/', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', 'A', '>', '<', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', 'B', '>', 'О', '.', ' ', 'А', '.', '<', '/', 'S', 'U', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', 'B', '>', '\n', '<', '/', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'D', '.', '7', '0', '1', '>']
<FIELD.1109>
0.286
</FIELD.1109>
=============================================
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно удалить все строки с "None"?
Желаемый результат:

```
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>0</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.1109>
нет
</FIELD.1109>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>0</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
=============================================
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>1</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>100</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.701>
<SUBFIELD.3>10000768</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Шерстюченко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>О. А.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.701>
<FIELD.1109>
0.286
</FIELD.1109>
=============================================
```

Answer (score 3):

Немного допилил код из вопроса.

Попробуйте:

```
text = """\
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>0</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
None
<FIELD.1109>
нет
</FIELD.1109>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>0</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
=============================================
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>1</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>100</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.701>
<SUBFIELD.3>10000768</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Шерстюченко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>О. А.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.701>
<FIELD.1109>
0.286
</FIELD.1109>
=============================================
"""

prefixes = 'None'
lines = [line for line in text.splitlines() if not line.startswith(prefixes)]
text = '\n'.join(lines)
print(text)
```

Результат:

```
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>0</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.1109>
нет
</FIELD.1109>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>0</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
=============================================
<FIELD.1107>
<SUBFIELD.F>1</SUBFIELD.F><SUBFIELD.J>1</SUBFIELD.J><SUBFIELD.R>0</SUBFIELD.R><SUBFIELD.S>0</SUBFIELD.S><SUBFIELD.W>0</SUBFIELD.W><SUBFIELD.Z>0</SUBFIELD.Z>
</FIELD.1107>
<PUBLICATION_LEVEL>100</PUBLICATION_LEVEL>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.701>
<SUBFIELD.3>10000768</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Шерстюченко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>О. А.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.701>
<FIELD.1109>
0.286
</FIELD.1109>
=============================================
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ. "None", действительно, удалились, но теперь на их месте, просто, пустая строка + получился "наплыв" тегов один на другой.

Comment: @Ireen1985, запускал мой код и не увидел пустых строк на месте `None`. Добавил результат в ответ

Answer (score 1):

С использованием регулярных выражений.

```
text = ваш текст

import re

new_text = re.sub("\nNone(.)*?\n", "\n", text)

print (new_text)
```

*PS. Если первая строка начинается с None, то данное выражение его не удалит. Но у вас первая строка не None, поэтому можно и так.*